# Grid to array[][] or finding items in each cell

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a grid 3x3 which contains 9 images. Is it possible to convert it to Images array[][], or just loop through every cell of my grid?

The point is in every of my 9 cells I have one image. All I want is to know which image is in specific cell.

EDIT

Here is my XAML code but It is just to create cells on my layout

```
<Grid x:Name="Map">
        <!-- Row and coulmns definition -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="128*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Canvas & Components  -->

        <Canvas
        x:Name="MyCanvas"
        Background="Azure"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Grid.RowSpan="3">
        </Canvas>
        <Button Background="Chocolate" Content="Spin" Name="SpinButton" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Click="SpinButton_Click" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="15,36,12,12" />
    </Grid>
```

I mostly do everyting in C# code behid. 
I am animating images using Storyboard class and finally set my 9 images to specific positions ( every image is in each of 9 cells ) .
I get Your code also tried to change Image to FrameworkElement but anyway it just sees Canvas Element. Maybe there is an option to take Elements from specific coordinates?

Adding images C#:

```
 public List<Image> SetImages(String order)
        {
            List<Image> line = new List<Image>();

            for (int i = 0; i < imagesQty; i++)
            {
                Image img1 = new Image();
                img1.Source = ananasImage;
                img1.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
                img1.Width = 200;
                img1.Height = 120;
                if (order.Equals("left"))
                {
                    line.Add(img1);
                    Canvas.SetTop(img1, -200);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(img1, 0);
                    MyCanvas.Children.Add(img1);
                }
                else if (order.Equals("middle"))
                {
                    line.Add(img1);
                    Canvas.SetTop(img1, -200);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(img1, 180);
                    MyCanvas.Children.Add(img1);
                }

                else if (order.Equals("right"))
                {
                    line.Add(img1);
                    Canvas.SetTop(img1, -200);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(img1, 360);
                    MyCanvas.Children.Add(img1);
                }

            }

            return line;
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the code as it is now?

Comment: There is just row && column definitions. Storyboard put images into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Children` property of your `Grid` to enumerate the child controls. Also, you can use the `Grid.GetRow` and `Grid.GetColumn` methods to know on what row/column a control is. From there, it's just a matter of stiching the bits together:

```
int row = 3;
int column = 2;

var image = grid.Children.OfType<Image>().FirstOrDefault(i => Grid.GetRow(i) == row && Grid.GetColumn(i) == column);

if (image != null)
{
    // Found the picture on line 3 and column 2
}
```

---

Also, if you want to know in which line/column your images are, you need to add them to the grid in first place:

```
if (order.Equals("left"))
{
    line.Add(img1);
    Grid.SetColumn(img1, 0);
    Grid.SetLine(img1, 0);
    Map.Children.Add(img1);
}
else if (order.Equals("left"))
{
    line.Add(img1);
    Grid.SetColumn(img1, 1);
    Grid.SetLine(img1, 0);
    Map.Children.Add(img1);
}
// and so on
```

Comment: image is null all the time ;/

Comment: Where are you adding your pictures?

Comment: Edited. I think I got the point I am not adding my images to my grid. Anyway I cant add my images to Grid because they are already childrens of Canvas. Whats the solution then ?;(

Comment: Why aren't you adding the images directly to the grid? Use `Grid.SetRow` and `Grid.SetColumn` to tell in which row/column they should be put

Comment: Because I cant add Image, I can add just FrameworkElemet. When I am trying to add Image then " Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid.SetRow(System.Windows.FrameworkElement, int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: ?? I don't understand why you would have this error, Image *is* a FrameworkElement https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Add you elements directly to the grid, not to the canvas. I edited my answer